# Yii cookie not being deleted on logout

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii

I am using the Yii framework and I currently have a problem where on logout, the associated cookie does not seem to be deleted. This only seems to occur when the user has selected "remember me". This is causing users to automatically log in again, after logging out.

I'm working on a dating site, so this is quite a big problem as people may visit while at internet cafe's etc.

I have not changed the default logout method, but have changed the session in config. I have configured as following, to allow sessions to be carried across our multiple servers and services.

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'autoCreateSessionTable' => false,
    'sessionName' => 'name', // renamed for privacy
    'cookieMode' => 'allow',
    'cookieParams' => array(
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => '.domain.com', // renamed for privacy
        'httpOnly' => false,
    ),
),
```

I can't seem to find a solution for this, nor anyone with a similar problem.

Wondering if anyone has any idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable this functionality completely you need to set AllowAutoLogin to false for CWebUser.

See the API reference here

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#allowAutoLogin-detail

The default value is false, so I'm assuming this has been set to to true somewhere in your configuration file.

Comment: We would still like the option to "remember me", which would use this feature. So turning it off completely doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Curious, just to confirm, you're talking about users who have logged in and have never ticked the remember me box on that machine?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify that. I believe it only occurs when they choose "remember me". My understanding though is that when you log out, it should also kill the cookie. I'll amend the question also.

Comment: I think maybe you just need to concentrate on the wording. For instance my on-line banking does the same thing with auto login but the remember me includes the following warning. 

  "Warning: Don’t tick this box if you’re using a public or shared  computer" There's no way around this, otherwise you'd have to some how know where the user was logging on from.